# C++ Prime Number Program not recognizing 3?

Tags: c++

My program is supposed to detect prime numbers from 1 to 100 and save them to a file.

For some reason, it does not recognize 3 but mistakenly recognizes some multiples (27, 33, etc) of 3 as prime.

Code follows...

```
/* This program will use a function determine if a number is prime.
When called this function will be used to determine all 
prime numbers from 1- 100 and save them to a file*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int);// function prototype

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("prime.txt");
    bool result;
    int num; // variable to hold integer number
    for (num = 1; num >= 1 && num <= 100; num++)
    {
        result =isPrime(num);
        if (result == true)
        {
            fout << num<< endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << num << " is not prime." <<endl;
        }
    }

    fout.close();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



bool isPrime(int test)
{
    //define prime as a bool integer
    bool prime;

    // check for 2, a prime number that will not be caught by for loop algorithm
    if (test == 2) 
    {
        prime = true;
    }
    // eliminate all even numbers other than 2
    else if ( test%2 == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
    // eliminate 0
    else if ( test == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
    //eliminate 1, which is not prime or composite
    else if ( test == 1)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
    // if test is not yet determined, check using algorithm 
    // this algorithm returns the remainder of a number (test)
    // divided by an integer (i) in the range of i = 1
    // to i = sqrt(number) 
    else
    {
        for(int i = 1; i <= (sqrt(test));i++)
        {
            if (test%i == 0)
            {
                prime = false;


            }

            else if (test%i != 0)
            {
                prime = true;

            }
        }

    }


    if (prime == true)
    {
        cout << "The number " <<test << " is prime." <<endl;
    }


    return prime;
```

EDIT for code fix:

```
        /* This program will use a function determine if a number is prime.
When called this function will be used to determine all 
prime numbers from 1- 100 and save them to a file*/

#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;


bool isPrime(int);// function prototype

int main()
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open("prime.txt");
    bool result;
    int num; // variable to hold integer number
    for (num = 1; num >= 1 && num <= 100; num++)
    {
        result =isPrime(num);
        if (result == true)
        {
            fout << num<< endl;
        }
        else 
        {
            cout << num << " is not prime." <<endl;
        }
    }

    fout.close();



    system("pause");
    return 0;
}



bool isPrime(int test)
{
    //define prime as a bool integer
    bool prime;
    double sqrt_num = sqrt(test);

    //check for number 2 which algorithm wont catch, but is prime
    if (test ==2)
    {
        return true;
    }


    // check if even and return false
    else if ( test% 2 == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }


    //eliminate 1, which is not prime or composite, and 0.
    else if ( test == 0 || test == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }
    // if test is not yet determined, check using algorithm 
    // this algorithm returns the remainder of a number (test)
    // divided by an integer (i) in the range of i = 1
    // to i = sqrt(number) 
    else
    {
        for(int i = 3; i <= sqrt_num;i+=2)
        {
            if (test%i == 0)
            {
                return false;

            }

        }

    }

    return true;



}
```

Comment: The reason it returns true is because the last number tested for 27 (5) changes prime to true, because ``27 % 5 != 0``

Comment: Stepping through calls of `isPrime` that aren't working would easily tell you.

Comment: @ThreeFx Thanks, I thought that might be it, but when I tried to fix  it by adding a counter to add up my truth values so that only numbers that were returning remainders for all i values were considered prime, it didn't seem to use my for loop at all. It only returned responses for 0-2. I have a feeling that I am making this assignment more difficult than it needs to be...

Comment: @cylonbaby you can safely return false if your number divides i without remainder because it means the number is representable by ``i * (n/i)`` which makes it composite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest error in your code is your for-loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= (sqrt(test));i++)
{
    if (test%i == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }

    else if (test%i != 0)
    {
        prime = true;

    }
}
```

If we step through if for your false test cases 3 and 27, we see that for 3 it is this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 1; i++)
{
    if (3 % 1 == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
    else if (3 % 1 != 0)
    {
        prime = true;
    }
}
```

The loop will be computed once, and the result (false) returned. The reason for this is that your loop starts with 1 and because every number is divisible by 1, every number which is only checked for 1 will always be composite. To fix this we just start with the number 2. If we do this, we have to set an initial value for "prime" because otherwise we would return a null value. Our initial value will be true, which means every number is prime until proven otherwise which, conveniently, is exactly what our for loop does.

The second error occurs when you reach the last iteration of the loop for 27:

```
//i == 5
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
{
    if (27 % 5 == 0)
    {
        prime = false;
    }
    else if (27 % 5 != 0)
    {
        prime = true;
    }
}
```

Because the last iteration sets prime to true, true is returned, which is obviously false. A possible solution is to exit the loop if we encounter an i for which `number % i == 0` holds, as this means we have found a valid factor for said number.

**TL; DR**: Solving the errors we got:

- start with the number 2 instead of one to get rid of the corner case 3 (and 2 as well)
- if a valid factor is found the number is **definitely** composite and we set prime to false and exit the loop because we found a result.

---

Using the fixes and simplifying we get:

```
bool isPrime(int number)
{
    // special cases 0 and 1
    if (i == 0 || i == 1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    // else check from i = 2 to sqrt(number) if any of them divides the number
    // if yes, the number is not prime and it returns false.
    for (int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++)
    {
        if (number % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    // if the number is not 0 or 1 and has passed the loop, it must be prime,
    // hence we can return true    
    return true;
}
```

A small optimisation to make would be checking if it is even and if not just testing division by odd numbers. We would then replace the for-loop by:

```
if (number % 2 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(number); i=i+2)
{
    if (number % i == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: All of this is very nice but has nothing to do with the original question

Comment: @icepack I updated my answer to fix the bugs in the questioners code

Comment: Thank you, I will try a format like this and see what I end up with. I thought I was making it more complicated than needed, but time is not really my ally as I have two "suuuuuper bored" children breathing down my neck as I study =) . I will check in again if I still cannot get it.

Comment: @cylonbaby Let me know if any further problems arise.

Comment: that worked beautifully, thank you! I was having trouble finding a way to end the loop after finding falsehood before, I don't know why I hadn't thought of using return at that point. << noob problems.

Comment: @cylonbaby Other than a return you could also have used a ``break``

Answer (score 0):

`(int)sqrt(3)` is `1`, every `test%1` will return 0 because division by 1 has no remainder.

You should stop the loop once you find proof that the number is not prime. If you keep it going the result will be misleading.

Note: `sqrt()` is an expensive function. Consider saving its result in a variable so you don't have to run it every loop.

Comment: Thanks! I will take note of and apply the sqrt() fix.

Answer (score 0):

Since you start the loop with `i = 1`, the condition `test%i == 0` is always true.

So you should start it with `i = 2`, which will allow you to test numbers greater than or equal to 4.

In addition, you should `break` the loop once you set `prime = false`.

You will have to test 3 separately, since `2 > sqrt(3)`.

---

A few suggestions for improvement:

```
bool isPrime(int number)
{
    // Handle 0 and 1
    if (number < 2)
        return false;

    // Handle 2 and 3
    if (number < 4)
        return true;

    // Handle numbers that are not adjacent to a multiple of 6
    if (number%2==0 || number%3==0)
        return false;

    // Calculate once
    int root = (int)sqrt(number);

    // Check divisibility by numbers that are equal to -1(mod6)
    for (int i=5; i<=root; i+=6)
    {
        if (number%i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    // Check divisibility by numbers that are equal to +1(mod6)
    for (int i=7; i<=root; i+=6)
    {
        if (number%i == 0)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```